# Generate encrypted files that the user (whose computer it is generated on) cannot decrypt it

Tags: encryption

I'm a bit of a layman here and would be after a Python-based solution to this.

I would want a python-based application approach that is capable of generating data (e.g. csv file) that is locked immediately upon writing it, and it is not possible for the user to decrypt its contents on that end but rather a proxy individual (who holds a the encryption key or cipher, for example).

Hopefully that makes sense? Would love some help on this!

Comment: What does keep the user from keeping a database where `|i|p[i]|c[i] |` is a row of plaintext and the corresponding ciphertext? What is your actual aim?

Comment: Please read [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/101423/102678) answer I did a while back as it should answer this question too without me having to repeat myself.

Comment: Asymmetric cryptography perchance? https://nitratine.net/blog/post/asymmetric-encryption-and-decryption-in-python/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible using [RSA asymmetric encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)). There are two keys, one public, which is used for encryption, and one private, which is used for decryption. You will create data (e.g. csv formatted string) in python that will only be stored in RAM memory, that will look something like this:

```
data1;data2;data3;
data4;data5;data6;
...
```

Then using your python application you will encrypt data using the proxy user's public RSA key and write it to your file system. Please keep in mind that this way you can only encrypt data as large as the RSA key length, so if you have 2,048-bit RSA key, you can only encrypt data up to 2,048 bits long. Also, asymmetric encryption isn't that fast. Because of this, RSA isn't intended for raw data encryption. In addition, using public key cryptography doesn't make sense without [PKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure).

Maybe a better solution would be implementing [key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_exchange) (e.q. Diffie-Hellman) between python application and proxy individual and then encrypting the data with the exchanged key using symmetric encryption (e.q. AES-256).

Comment: "... you can only encrypt data as large as the RSA key length, so ..." No. Nowadays, we use (some padded form of) RSA to encrypt a key which is then used to encrypt the data using symmetric-key cipher.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by others, a user can create a ciphertext that they themselves cannot later decrypt by using assymetric cryptography.

- Generate assymetric key pair $K_1, K_2$
- Give $K_1$ to the user
- User can encrypt plaintext $P$ as ciphertext $C=encrypt(K_1,P)$
- Only key $K_2$ can decrypt $C$ so the user that only has $K_1$ cannot decrypt it

This approach requires the user to have some sort of access to the plaintext. It seems like your goal is for the user not to gain knowledge of $P$ either, and this is trickier to do. If they have full access to the hardware the program is running on then it's near impossible to completely protect the data the program generates.